# join anonymous type to Entity in LINQ to Entity

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have been learning LINQ Lamda expressions while using entity framework.
But not able to find out why my code (mentioned below) is not working or is there any other way to achieve it?

tbl_A is an entity.

```
var tbl_A = from e in db.TBL_A select e;
```

Based on some filter on tbl_A, two columns are extracted in an anonymous type.

```
if(value != 0) {tbl_A = tbl_A.Where(a=>a.Id == value);}
var anoType = tbl_A.Select(a=>new {ID = a.ID,NAME = a.NAME});
```

I am trying to fetch all records from tbl_B where ID and NAME (both matches) in above anonymous type.

```
var blockUpdate = db.tbl_B.Join(anoType, a => new { a.ID, a.NAME }, 
b => new { b.ID, b.NAME },(a, b) => new { a });
```

it is giving a compile time error - the type arguments for method can't be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Do both `ID`s and `NAME`s have _exactly_ the same types? For example you can't have one `ID` as `int` and the other as `int?`.

Comment: ok problem seems to be with anonymous type. This is working - var blockUpdate = tbl_B.Join(anoType, a => a.ID, b => b.ID, (a, b) => a); @Gert - ID and Name both have same datatype in both tables

Comment: @GertArnold - Apologies - After few hours I found out that you were damn right. Should have given a careful thought to your suggestion. This worked                                                                                          var blockUpdate = db.tbl_B.Join(anoType, a => new { a.ID, a.NAME }, 
b => new { (short?)b.ID, b.NAME },(a, b) => a);

Comment: Even under the microscope I don't see any difference :) What did you change?

Comment: @GertArnold - in one table column ID was nullable but in other not-null. Conversion of ID column to nullable short (short?) made the difference. Not sure but when I started writing LINQ query expression (not lambda) intellisense was able to hint me about it.